# Table Input Value returns NaN with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to return the value of the quantity class and I keep getting NaN. I'm able to access the price class but not the quantity. The difference being that quantity has an input.

```
 <body>
   <tr>
     <td class="item pr-5">Sample</td>
     <td class="price pr-5">25.33</td>
     <td class="quantity pr-5"><input type="number" value="1" /></td>
     <td class="subtotal pr-5">$25.33</td>
     <td>
       <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove">
         Remove Item
       </button>
     </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('tbody tr').each(function (i, ele) {
    var price = parseFloat($(ele).children('.price').text());
    console.log(price);
    var quantity = parseFloat($(ele).children('.quantity').text());
    console.log(quantity); // NaN
    var subtotal = price * quantity;
    // console.log(subtotal);
  });
});
```

Comment: input is the child for <td>, so select like this: `var quantity = parseFloat($(ele).children('.quantity').children('input').val())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `find()` method rather than using two `children` method the reach input tag. And take value from input tag, use `val()` rather then `text()`.

`var quantity = parseFloat($(ele).find('.quantity input').val());`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tbody tr').each(function(i, ele) {
    var price = parseFloat($(ele).children('.price').text());
    console.log(price);
    var quantity = parseFloat($(ele).find('.quantity input').val());
    console.log(quantity); // NaN
    var subtotal = price * quantity;
    // console.log(subtotal);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="item pr-5">Sample</td>
      <td class="price pr-5">25.33</td>
      <td class="quantity pr-5"><input type="number" value="1" /></td>
      <td class="subtotal pr-5">$25.33</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove">
         Remove Item
       </button>
      </td>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because of this line `<td class="quantity pr-5"><input type="number" value="1" /></td>`. This line does not have `text` but it has another children

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tbody tr').each(function(i, ele) {
    var price = parseFloat($(ele).children('.price').text());
    console.log(price);
    var quantity = parseFloat($(ele).children('.quantity').text());
    console.log(quantity); // NaN
    var subtotal = price * quantity;
    // console.log(subtotal);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="item pr-5">Sample</td>
      <td class="price pr-5">25.33</td>
      <td class="quantity pr-5"><input type="number" value="1" /></td>
      <td class="subtotal pr-5">$25.33</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove">
         Remove Item
       </button>
      </td>

  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I was able to solve with:

```
var quantity = parseFloat($(ele).children('.quantity').children().val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) @jooami! We hope you like it here.

I think you may be interested in being able to recalculate to subtotal and total when the `.quantity` changes (or when a discount is applied):

```
$('tbody tr input').on('input', function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var price = +$tr.find('.price').text();
    console.log(price);
    var quantity = +$tr.find('.quantity input').val();
    console.log(quantity);
    var subtotal = price * quantity;
    console.log(subtotal);
})
.trigger('input');
```

See demo below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tbody tr input').on('input', function() {
        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var price = +$tr.find('.price').text();
        console.log(price);
        var quantity = +$tr.find('.quantity input').val();
        console.log(quantity);
        var subtotal = price * quantity;
        console.log(subtotal);
    })
    .trigger('input');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="item pr-5">Sample</td>
      <td class="price pr-5">25.33</td>
      <td class="quantity pr-5"><input type="number" value="1" /></td>
      <td class="subtotal pr-5">$25.33</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove">
         Remove Item
       </button>
      </td>

  </tbody>
</table>
```